# Starting packager bug in react native

Tags: react-native

I’m pretty new to programming .So I installed react native in the way as it’s written in facebook’s tutorial, now when I cd to my project and type npm start  it’s starting packager endlessly.Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to visit the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and also read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so you can learn what types of questions are accepted here, how to write questions, and how to use this site effectively

Comment: Pls, paste the error screenshot.